# Re-size an image in Office Picture Manager

Tags: image, pixel, office-2007

want to change the pixel for my image to 951x211.when type in 951x211 it automatically display as 594 x 211.want to put my image as a banner in my Home Page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Photoshop is the solution to my problems above once i set the width and height..it becomes fixed, saved as image in desktop, and when i open in office picture manager it widths and height doesn't  change.